# Extract value based on max value - pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, max

I am trying to extract a value ('*location*') based on the highest value in another column ('*total_cases*') and assign it to `highest_no_new`

My previous dataframe where I want to extract the value from is called `no_new_cases`

I want to pick out the '*location*' with the highest number of '*total_cases*' from `no_new_cases`

I am able to access the highest number of '*total_cases*', but not the location:

```
highest_no_new = no_new_cases['total_cases'].max()
```

Please can you help return the 'location'?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`idxmax`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.idxmax.html):

```
df.loc[df['total_cases'].idxmax(), 'location']
```

Comment: thanks! edited to.. highest_no_new = no_new_cases.loc[no_new_cases['total_cases'].idxmax(), 'location']  which has worked :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`iloc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html) method:

```
df['highest_no_new'] = df.iloc[df.total_cases.argmax()]['location']
```

**Example**:

```
>>> d = {'location': [1, 2], 'total_cases': [3, 4]}
>>> df = pd.DataFrame(d)
>>> df
   location  total_cases
0         1            3
1         2            4

>>> df.iloc[df.total_cases.argmax()]['location']
2
```